# Как преобразовать из файла числа в списки, python

Tags: python

Eсть файл txt в котором:

```
3486    2928    2840    3148    3102  
4156    2568    3328    2814    2946  
3116    3084    3966    3744    3086  
3372    2500    3676    3546    3196  
2866    2912    3302    2886    2966  
3276    2322    3186    3020    2508
```

Я бы хотел всё это сделать в списки:

```
[3486,  2928,   2840,   3148,   3102]  
[4156,  2568,   3328,   2814,   2946]
```

и т.д

Comment: Читаете файл построчно, каждую стрку бьете на элементы через split и получаете результат.

Comment: да, разобрался:
f = open('text.txt')  
for line in f.readlines():  
    t = line.split()  
    t = [int(n) for n in t]

Comment: Если вы хотите анализировать данные позже, то можно dataframe вернуть вместо списков: `df = pandas.read_csv("data.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[int(i) for i in l.split()] for l in open('text.txt')]
```

or

```
with open('text.txt') as txt:
    [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in txt]
```